# Updating a Logitech Unifying receiver

Tags: 19.10, logitech-unifying

After upgrading to 19.10 from 16.04 LTS, I get an update for a unifying receiver. When I try to install it, it says it can't be updated while in use. Since this unifying receiver from Logitech controls both my input devices of mouse & keyboard, exactly how is someone to do this?

Comment: You can't actively be using the keyboard/mouse. Connect another input device set. If this is a laptop, use the built-in keyboard and trackpad.

Comment: Not a laptop. So, what you are saying is that I have to go buy another keyboard & mouse to only be used when the unifying receiver has an update? That sounds just a bit dumb.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the Logitech Unifying receiver while it's in use. Since your Logitech mouse/keyboard are your only input devices, update this way...

Go to:

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360033207154-Logitech-Unifying-Receiver-Update

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035037273

Download the .exe updater file and place it on a USB flash drive.

Unplug the Unifying receiver and take it to any other Windows computer and perform the update there.

Comment: Thank you for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [walk-through for 21.10](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/10/26/step-by-step-logitech-unifying-software-ubuntu-21-10-installation/3/) which I don't know if this will work for 19.10.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:solaar-unifying/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install solaar

## I selected yes to use plugdev group

# Add your user to the group if not already there
sudo adduser <youruser> plugdev
sudo apt update

# Probably should have restarted
solaar
```

Now you should be able to pair the device

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `fwupdmgr get-devices` and search through the list and find the Unifying Receiver and copy the Device ID

```
└─Unifying Receiver:
  Device ID:          fa2e97deea7317b3aef6a652bd6f252f606a9d76
  Summary:            Miniaturised USB wireless receiver
  Current version:    RQR24.10_B0036
  Bootloader Version: BOT03.01_B0008
  Vendor:             HIDRAW:0x046D|USB:0x046D
  Install Duration:   30 seconds
  Update State:       Success
  GUIDs:              cc4cbfa9-bf9d-540b-b92b-172ce31013c6
                      fcf55bf5-767b-51ce-9c17-f6f538c4ee96
                      279ed287-3607-549e-bacc-f873bb9838c6
  Device Flags:       • Updatable
                      • Supported on remote server
                      • Unsigned Payload
```

Run the command `fwupdmgr update fa2e97deea7317b3aef6a652bd6f252f606a9d76`. Replace the ID in the command with your device ID.